# Search and Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I need little help.
Peace everyone, hope that you are doing great.

I made an app with tableview, I wanted to add a searchbar to my tableview, so I found a tutorial how to add searchbar to tableview, but the in the tutorial it was just an list with item but not items that when you type those items they move you to Viewcontroller with textview. Different from tutorial, my app is so, when you type one of those items they move you to Viewcontroller with textview. But better you can see how my tablview looks like:
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

It looks nice, it also looks nice when I use search-bar :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But problem is, when you use search, it gives me different data from different variable, as in image:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Hope that I was clear, and hope someone will explain me how to fix this issue.

Peace.

Here is my tablview code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var FirstTableArray = [String]()
    var passThisArray = [String]()

    var filteredVerbs = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        self.tableView.reloadData()




        // This array will display on your tableviewcell.
        FirstTableArray = [åadlyde, åanbefale, åansette, åarbeide, åavslå, åavstå, åbade, åbanke, åbarbere, åbe, åbearbeide, åbedra, åbedøve, åbegynne, åbehandle, åbeite, åbeskrive, åbestemme…]

        //You can pass element of this array
        passThisArray = ["å adlyde", "å anbefale", "å ansette", "å arbeide", "å avslå", "å avstå", "å bade", "å banke", "å barbere", "å be", "å bearbeide", "å bedra", "å bedøve", "å begynne", "å behandle"…]

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if(passThisArray.count > 3){




            if (self.resultSearchController.active)
            {
                return self.filteredVerbs.count;

            }
            else
            {
            return self.passThisArray.count
            }

        }

    return FirstTableArray.count


    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.text = passThisArray[indexPath.row]


        if (self.resultSearchController.active)
        {
            Cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredVerbs[indexPath.row]

            return Cell

        }
        else
        {
            Cell.textLabel?.text = self.passThisArray[indexPath.row]

            return Cell

        }


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewwController

            //Get the Index of selected Cell
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //assign string to next view controller instance from selected cell.
            vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]

            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

                vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[filteredVerbs.count]

            }

        }


    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        self.filteredVerbs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.passThisArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.filteredVerbs = array as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: the third image is here, because I cant post it there: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOiMj.png

Comment: You should post the code here instead of screenshots. Paste it, select it, then press Ctrl+K

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: From the looks of it, taking a blind guess, it seems that you may not have taken the search into account in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Please post the code.

Comment: yes man, @Arc676 and Jaycee, here you have the code of my tableview.

Comment: @Losiowaty so im missing some code at didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Still no one can find the sulution?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that your problem lies in this method, in the selected line :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewwController

            //Get the Index of selected Cell
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            //assign string to next view controller instance from selected cell.
            vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]

            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

                vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[filteredVerbs.count] // <<---

            }
        }
    }
```

If the search is active, you should rather take your `FirstString` this way `self.filteredVerbs[indexPath.row]`.

---

With knowledge from comments : 
It seems there is no easy way to map between values stored in these two arrays.

Also, this is not an ideal way to store this data. It is not flexible and mixes data with presentation, which should generally be avoided. I'd suggest creating a struct to store the data, something like this :

```
class Flexion : NSObject {
    var infinitiv:String = ""
    var presens:String = ""
    var preteritum:String = ""
    var perfektum:String = ""
    var english:String = ""

    init(infinitiv:String, presens:String, preteritum:String, perfektum:String, english:String) {
        self.infinitiv = infinitiv
        self.presens = presens
        self.preteritum = preteritum
        self.perfektum = perfektum
        self.english = english
    }
}
```

The main benefit in your case would be to have only one array with objects from which your table view is sourced. Thw whole thing would also get more readable and become easier for further upkeep.

So your code from the original question would become something like this :

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var FirstTableArray = [Flexion]()
    var filteredVerbs = [Flexion]()

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar

        //create your objects like this :
        var åadlyde = Flexion(infinitiv: "å adlyde", presens: "adlyder", preteritum: "adlød", perfektum: "har adlydt", english: "obey")
        //create the rest of them

        FirstTableArray = [åadlyde, åanbefale, åansette, åarbeide, åavslå, åavstå, åbade, åbanke, åbarbere, åbe, åbearbeide, åbedra, åbedøve, åbegynne, åbehandle, åbeite, åbeskrive, åbestemme…]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            return self.filteredVerbs.count
        }

        return FirstTableArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            let verb = self.filteredVerbs[indexPath.row] as Flexion
            Cell.textLabel?.text = verb.infinitiv
        } else {
            let verb = self.FirstTableArray[indexPath.row] as Flexion
            Cell.textLabel?.text = verb.infinitiv
        }
        return Cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
            var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

            if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
                vc.verb = filteredVerbs[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                vc.verb = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]
            }
        }

    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredVerbs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.infinitiv CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = (self.FirstTableArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.filteredVerbs = array as! [Flexion]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

You'd also need to make neccessary changes in `"detailView"` view controller - adding a `verb` variable of `Flexion` type and changing the way you present the data to user.

This way, there is no need for this "mapping" between arrays.

NOTE: note the change in the `NSPredicate` - it will now check only the `infinitiv` version of the word.

Comment: It is almost correct, the result, the textview text now is from passThisArray = ["å adlyde"], but passthisArray is just the title, I want the variable, which is from : FirstTableArray = [åadlyde], hope you understand me.

Comment: Maybe I have to write code about searching the content of FirstTableArray also, which stores the variables?

Comment: @ILike Logic, yes, you need to somehow be able to find the content from your `FirstTableArray` based on the indexPath from the filtered list.

Comment: Still no one can find the sulution?

Comment: What type are the objects stored in `FirstTableArray`? Am I right to assume that they inherit from `String`? (based on `FirstTableArray` declaration). Could you post the code of this class?

Comment: Hei @Losiowaty , firsttablearrey contains variables that contain string.         FirstTableArray = [åadlyde, åanbefale, åansette, åarbeide, åavslå, åavstå, åbade, åbanke, åbarbere, åbe, åbearbeide, åbedra, åbedøve, åbegynne, åbehandle, åbeite, åbeskrive, åbestemme…]
for example this is one of the variables: var åadlyde = "\nInfinitiv:\n\nå adlyde\n\n\n\nPresens:\n\nadlyder\n\n\n\nPreteritum:\n\nadlød\n\n\n\nPerfektum:\nhar\n\nadlydt\n\n\n\nEnglish:\n\nObey"

Comment: I've expanded my answer